# Iframe height will not resize with method "onresize="?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, height

I have an iframe and its height will automatically be worked out, 
But when I resize the screen the height is not updating itself to match the iframes content height here is my work can someone point out where I am going wrong?

Js

```
 function resizeIframe(obj) {
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
```

iframe

```
<body>

<iframe name="Stack" src="index.html" frameborder="0" width="100%" scrolling="no" id="iframe" onload="resizeIframe(this);" onresize="resizeIframe(this);"/>

</body>
```

Im using `onresize` on the iframe to try and make the resizeIframe function "play" again when the iframe/window is resized but its not working I also tried `onresize` on the body tag still nothing 
Please can someone point me in the right direction,
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the resize() handler from the parent document on the iframe:

```
$('iframe').resize(function() {} );
```

Comment: $('iframe').resize(function() { resizeIframe(); } ); doesn't solve this.